# Curve and sweeping line intersection: continuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, plane-curves

> Let $\gamma$ be a simple, piecewise differentiable, closed plane curve.
>   Assume that the slope of the tangent to $\gamma$, where defined, is never $m$.
>   Show that the function $ x \mapsto \sup \{ ||\mathrm{u_2} - \mathrm{u_1}||, \ \mathrm{u_1}, \mathrm{u_2} \in \gamma \cap \mathcal{l} (m,x)\}$ is continuous over $\mathbb{R}$.
>   Here, $\mathcal{l} (m,c)$ is the line in the plane having slope $m$ and intercept $c$, while $||\circ||$ is the Euclidean distance.

I think I can prove this elementarily, by picking a parametrization for $\gamma$ and working with delta/epsilons and standard analysis.
However, it would be nice if there were any other less sweaty ways of proving (or disproving!) this, or even merely alternative ways.
I would be bewildered if there were no more elegant framework in which this result is dealt with immediately.

Comment: If this is a simple closed smooth curve, there is no such $m$. So corners are essential. At any rate, a local calculation based on approximating pieces of curve by respective tangent lines makes it very easy ... away from corners.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, corners are essentials. The particular case I am interested in is that of a closed simple lattice walk in the plane (i.e., you start from the origin and move a unitary step either horizontally or vertically). I want to show that the sweep of any line other than the two axes is a continuous function. Which I can do the way you suggest, but dealing with corners is a problem. Hence my post. I am starting to think I need to restate my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> ### My own claim is false.
>
> As a counterexample, consider the outer contour of this figure as $\gamma$:
>   [image]
>   Take the y=x line and sweep.

For the ultimate application I need, I think I can still use a related result, but I don't know how to state it rigorously.